# How to make Thread1 to execute all samplers in a controller and Thread2 starts

Tags: jmeter

I have a below Testplan

[image]

In the transaction controller i mentioned 3 Samplers.Thread1 has to execute all the samplers and Thread2 has to execute it again.

But when i run the tests the samplers are executed differently with different threads.Before logout one Thread an another thread login has started.
[image]

could you please help me,How to to execute in this order
Thread1: Login, permission ,logout
Thread2: Login,permission,logout

Comment: Your Test plan is not properly configured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your "Samplers" are **outside** the Transaction Controller

   [image]
2. Each JMeter thread is absolutely independent, once started it will run all Samplers upside down (or according to the [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers)). So each thread will execute all Samplers you "mentioned"

   If you want first thread to run all the samplers then second thread to run all the samplers either put them under [Critical Section Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller) (it ensures that only one thread executes its children at a time) or play with [JMeter ramp-up settings](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period). However in both cases you will get concurrency of 1 online user only.

Comment: Thank you so much. is there any possibility in JMeter that ,1 account simulates 100 users to Login Website?

Comment: if you run the load test with 1 account you might encounter errors like 409.If you are executing  each thread after completion of previous thread you wont be able to achieve concurrency ,you should have multiple accounts to perform load test.